# JSOUP - Java create a new tag in the DOM

Tags: java, tags, jsoup, area

I'm trying to add a new tag "area" between somes existing "area" on a Web page in local using Jsoup.

My code is like :

```
<hmtl>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...a lot of <div>..
  <map name="diagram_map">
     <area id="area1" />
     <!-- I would like to insert a new area here-->
     <area id="area2" />
  </map>
</body>
<hmtl/>
```

I look before on the site if anyone had already the same issue but I didn't found.
I know how to select an existing "area" by the id :

```
   Element target = doc.getElementById("area1");
   Node target = doc.getElementById("area1");
```

But I don't know how to add a new "area" tag, I tried all the append, after/before but it write the new tag in the tag "area".

Thanks by advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import java.io.File;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class JsoupFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Document doc =  Jsoup.parse(new File("t2.html"), "UTF-8");
        doc.select("area#area1").after("<area id=\"newArea\" />");
        System.out.println(doc.html()); 
    }

}
```

Html

```
<hmtl>
<head>
</head>
<body>
...a lot of <div>..
  <map name="diagram_map">
     <area id="area1" />
     <area id="area2" />
  </map>
</body>
<hmtl/>
```

Output

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <hmtl>    ...a lot of 
   <div>
    .. 
    <map name="diagram_map"> <area id="area1"></area><area id="newArea"></area> <area id="area2"></area> </map>  
    <hmtl /> 
   </div>
  </hmtl>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, maybe it's my doc ? I have :`File in = new File (pathWebProject); <br/> Document doc = Jsoup.parse(in, "UTF-8");`

Comment: what does this gives in you html? I tested it with the html you gave and its working fine. :(

Comment: Humm it's return me, the area I choose on the select : "area1". My "doc" is correct ? Thanks for your answers

Comment: Updated with my complete program.

Comment: I'm sorry it's working !! thanks a lot i'm on this task since three hours ^^

Comment: Just when I modified my HTML code, The HTML area modified is on one line.. And it already did it before for others using of JSOUP.
Do you have an idea on how can I organize well my code when I modify it with JSOUP ? :))
@Syam S

Comment: That is because map and area is not recognized as standard html tags by jsoup. I'll try a way of formatting this. :)

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, I will search also.. I tell you if I find a way to do it.
@Syam S